# No gzip compression in response header using angular 4, litespeed cpanel

Tags: apache, angular, .htaccess, gzip

I built an app via angular cli-- Angular 4 (ng build --prod --bo) and uploaded on [https://armen.jahanbani.ir/](https://armen.jahanbani.ir/home) .

I tried every possible code for enabling gzip-compression via .htaccess but none of them worked.

Here's my .htaccess so far:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>



## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##





RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Here's my response headers:

```
accept-ranges:bytes
cache-control:public, max-age=604800
content-length:1343404
content-type:application/javascript
date:Wed, 02 Aug 2017 14:16:00 GMT
expires:Wed, 09 Aug 2017 14:16:00 GMT
last-modified:Wed, 02 Aug 2017 12:20:30 GMT
server:LiteSpeed
status:200
```

And request headers :

```
:authority:armen.jahanbani.ir
:method:GET
:path:/main.17622fc4e9e5f19aa68d.bundle.js
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6
alexatoolbar-alx_ns_ph:AlexaToolbar/alx-4.0.1
cache-control:no-cache
pragma:no-cache
referer:https://armen.jahanbani.ir/home
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
```

I even tried to force server to compress files with adding `Header append content-encoding: gzip` but that didn't work either and got an error.

Should I work on .htaccess and server, or something is wrong with my angular files?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to your Apache httpd.conf file?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to httpd.conf. The main domain has been created via wordpress and works fine! I think something else is missing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to install a node package called 'compression' to your project and that will enable the angular project to use gzip compression.

```
npm install --save compression
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enable gzip from WebAdmin directly? You can just add Compressible Types there too, it's more easier for me to setup gzip in this way.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to enable gzip from that, and it didn't work. I don't know what's wrong exactly. Simply, I use the .htaccess approach for my wordpress websites and it works.